# Сервер VDS упорно не видит index файлов

Tags: сервер, centos, веб-сервер, vds

Вообщем, имею VDS с панелью centos и isp менеджером, домен уже тоже прикрутил. В корне лежит файл `index.html` . Когда набираю адрес сайта `site.ru/index.html` все норм, а когда набираю просто `site.ru` то перебрасывает на главную страницу хостинга, или выдает ошибку 403. В чем может бить проблема? Где и что править, подскажите знающие люди. Буду очень Вам благодарен за помощь, а то я уже гугл задолбал со своими запросами.

Comment: кэш браузера очищали?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, чистил. Не помогает. Пока что решил проблему при помощи .htaccess но это кажется не правильное решение. Должно быть что-то другое. Или я ошибаюсь?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте создать .htaccess файл в корне папки домена, или дополнить существующий. Нужно добавить строчку:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html
```

Не уверен что поможет - если нет, скорее всего криво апач настроен.

Comment: Я так и сделал, но разве это правильное решение? Что то кажется мне это всеравно не то.

Comment: Если помогло - значит в самом апаче прописана опция DirectoryIndex глобально, в которой нет index.html по дефолту. Можете поменять настройку апача. Но я бы не парился по этому поводу.

Comment: Нет, как то хочется что бы было все по науке.

Comment: Пойду пороюсь в настройках апача, ато как то сам сразу и не догадался.

Comment: @ Гончаров Александр в настройках прописан DirectoryIndex index.html, знач не оно.